# SharePoint 2013 App solutions structure

Tags: 2013, workflow, app, visual-studio-2012

I have VS2012 app solution with two projects in it

1. A
2. B

The workflow is included to the **A** project and I would like to add this workflow to the **B** project. I have not found the workflow's elements in the Package manifest. The same in the Feature manifest. I have looked to the project's build events, but have not found helpful information in it.

Could I include workflow to the B project?